# Optimize function in R with constraints

Tags: r, optimization

I have this function

```
hazwil2 <- function(diam, flow, leng){
  psi2=((1/(2.31*100))*1050*((flow/140)^1.852)*leng*diam^-4.87)
  return(psi2)
}
```

I'm trying to use `optimize()` to minimize `psi2` by varying the value of diam. 
I'm not looking for an absolute minimum but for the smallest value of diam that will keep `psi2` below 2. Also, I should mention that `diam` is the diameter of a pipe, so it can only be a discrete values, 2, 3, 4, 5, or 6.

When I use:

```
optimize(
  f = hazwil2,
  interval = c(0.1,12),
  flow = 100,
  leng = 400
)
```

I get the largest possible value of `diam` (11.9), and a very small value for `psi2`. My function is monotonic so the minimization of `psi2` will always result in the largest possible `diam`. I guess I'm struggling to set the constraints for my `optimize()` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`uniroot()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/uniroot.html) finds the location where a curve/function crosses zero.  Subtract 2 from the PSI to find the minimum allowable diameter.   It crosses at 3.564, so 4 is the smallest integer that keeps psi under 2.

```
intercept   <- 2L
uniroot(
  function(x) hazwil2(x, 100, 400) - intercept ,
  interval = c(3, 4)
)

curve(expr=hazwil2(x, 100, 400), from=2.5, to=5)
abline(a=intercept, b=0, col="blue")
```

The [`curve()`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/curve.html) graph influenced the arbitrary decision to search diameters between 3 and 4.

```
Result of `uniroot()`:
$`root`
[1] 3.564091

$f.root
[1] -5.618425e-05

$iter
[1] 6

$init.it
[1] NA

$estim.prec
[1] 6.103516e-05
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Wibeasley, thank you for your answer. It works great. The next question I have is how to apply your function to a dataframe such as this:      structure(list(leng = c(100, 200, 300, 100, 200, 300, 100, 200, 
300), flow = c(100, 100, 100, 150, 150, 150, 200, 200, 200)), out.attrs = list(
    dim = c(leng = 3L, flow = 3L), dimnames = list(leng = c("leng=100", 
    "leng=200", "leng=300"), flow = c("flow=100", "flow=150", 
    "flow=200"))), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L
))      I tried apply() with no success

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by applying it to an entire dataset.  Do you want  to vary three predictor variables at once?  If so, I think you need to explicitly define the tradeoffs between the inputs (eg, would you rather have a 100'x4" pipe or a 150'x5' pipe, if they have roughly the same PSI).

Comment: With only a handful of discrete points, it's probably easiest to run them by hand through the function, and then decide among those under 2 PSI.

Comment: In your answer we have 100 for flow and 400 for leng. I would like to run the uniroot function on a dataset composed by 3 values of flow (100, 150, 200) and 3 values of length (100,200 and 300). I'm trying to use uniroot() with apply() to run your funcion on each combination of flow and leng in my dataset. Eventually I'll run the function on 10 values of flow and 10 of leng so it's not feasible to run them by hand. Thanks again

Comment: Y0u'd have to loop around `uniroot()` with something like `mapply()` or a function from the `purrr` package.  This is different enough to be it's own question.  Tag me on if if you'd like.  Consider spelling out what you're going to do with those 100 values (eg, do you find the best single option?  how?)

Comment: I wrote a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50978973/8060871 Thanks!