# Looping uniroot() on two arguments with sapply()

Tags: r, loops

This function that calculates the pressure loss in a pipe given its diameter, flowrate, and length.

```
hazwil2 <- function(diam, flow, leng){
  psi2=((1/(2.31*100))*1050*((flow/140)^1.852)*leng*diam^-4.87)
  return(psi2)
}
```

I'm looking for the smallest diameter that will keep the pressure loss within 2 psi. The range of diameters is between 2 and 12 inches. Using uniroot() and two arbitrary values for flow and length:

```
intercept   = 2L
uniroot(
  function(x) hazwil2(x, 100, 400) - intercept ,
  interval = c(2, 12)
)$root
```

Now I'm trying to loop uniroot on this dataset of values of flow and length

```
data <- read.csv(
  text = 
  "leng,flow
  100, 100
  200, 100
  300, 100
  100, 150
  200, 150
  300, 150
  100, 200
  200, 200
  300, 200",
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider generalizing your *unitroot* call for *f* and *l* params, and pass it in `mapply` (**m**ultiple apply) to iterate elementwise down the equal length vectors (i.e., columns, *flow* and *length* of dataframe):

```
find_root <- function(f, l) {
  intercept <- 2L
  uniroot(
    function(x) hazwil2(x, f, l) - intercept ,
    interval = c(2, 12)
  )$root
}

data$root <- mapply(find_root, data$flow, data$leng)

data
#   leng flow     root
# 1  100  100 2.681145
# 2  200  100 3.091243
# 3  300  100 3.359606
# 4  100  150 3.128141
# 5  200  150 3.606602
# 6  300  150 3.919727
# 7  100  200 3.489780
# 8  200  200 4.023564
# 9  300  200 4.372916
```

For a larger set which can potentially yield root issues, consider wrapping function call in `tryCatch` to return `NA`:

```
data <- expand.grid(leng = seq(100, 1000, by=100), flow = seq(10, 200, by=10))
data$root <- mapply(function(l,f) tryCatch(find_root(l,f), error=function(e) NA), 
                    data$flow, data$leng)
```

**Output**

```
head(data, 20)

#    leng flow     root
# 1   100   10       NA
# 2   200   10       NA
# 3   300   10       NA
# 4   400   10       NA
# 5   500   10       NA
# 6   600   10       NA
# 7   700   10       NA
# 8   800   10       NA
# 9   900   10       NA
# 10 1000   10       NA
# 11  100   20       NA
# 12  200   20       NA
# 13  300   20       NA
# 14  400   20       NA
# 15  500   20 2.023187
# 16  600   20 2.100367
# 17  700   20 2.167915
# 18  800   20 2.228178
# 19  900   20 2.282705
# 20 1000   20 2.332653
```

Comment: The answers aren't consistent with https://stackoverflow.com/a/50959297/1082435.  I believe the `leng` & `flow` parameters should be flipped in `mapply()`.

Comment: Good catch @wibeasley, I did incorrectly swap the `mapply` args.

Comment: Hi Parfait, your answer works great with the dataset of leng and flow posted in my question, but when I try it on a larger dataset such as `data=expand.grid(leng = seq(100, 1000, by=100), flow = seq(10, 200, by=10))` I get the error `values at end points not of opposite sign` Thanks again!

Comment: See update to wrap function call in `tryCatch` which that error applies to only 2 rows of the 200 rows.

Comment: Wow Parfait, it works great. But I think that you meant  `tryCatch(find_root(l,f)` instead of `tryCatch(find_lowest(l,f)`. Thanks again!

Comment: Whoops! Apparently, I repeated my earlier error of swapping *flow* and *leng*! See edit.

Answer (score 1):

This based on @Parfait's answer, and includes some graphs that came to mind during the [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50958860).  The first graph sets the *x* & *y* coordinates to `flow` and `leng` and displays the min diameter required to drop below 2 PSI.

```
data$diam_min        <- purrr::map2_dbl(.x=data$flow, .y=data$leng, ~find_root(f=.x, l=.y))
data$diam_min_pretty <- sprintf("diam min:\n%0.2f", data$diam_min)

library(ggplot2);  library(magrittr)
ggplot(data, aes(x=flow, y=leng, label=diam_min_pretty)) +
  geom_text()
```

[image: 13-points]

The second graph make each value of `leng` a contour line, and the min diameter replaces it on the *y* axis.  That open dot represents the solution to [Optimize function in R with constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50958860).

```
tidyr::crossing(leng=c(100, 200, 300, 400), flow=100:200) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(
    diam_min = purrr::map2_dbl(.x=flow, .y=leng, ~find_root(.x, .y)),
    leng     = factor(leng)
  ) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=flow, y=diam_min, color=leng)) +
  geom_line() +
  annotate("point", x=100, y=find_root(f=100, l=400), size=4, shape=1)
```

[image: level-curves]

I'm [still not sure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50958860/optimize-function-in-r-with-constraints#comment88949901_50959297) how you're going to choose the most desirable value (out of this set that achieves <2 psi), but maybe these visual relationships will help.

Comment: Wow wibesley thank you for your answer and your useful graphs.

Comment: I work for a local agency in California (http://rcdsantacruz.org/), we provide assistance to growers for water conservation. These are some videos about what we do:https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCvmpPlP2tzN7Xdv2qn_JzXw  . I'm asking this question to produce a table on how to size a manifold hose that serves many driptapes inserted into it in a strawberry field. The table will have the length of the hose in the columns and the length of the tapes in the rows. These will determine the minimum hose diameter to keep pressure loss low and irrigation uniform.

Comment: I'm glad the graphs were useful.  Consider hitting that up arrow whose hover text says "This answer is useful." :)  Thanks for explaining that applied scenario.  That's not what I was asking, but now I understand why my question didn't make sense. You don't have control over variables like length, but they're still going to change, based on the strawberry rows?  I didn't know how to decide the optimal point along the level curves (since they all represent the same PSI).  If that was the case, you'd introduce something like [utility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utility_maximization_problem).